# How to put color on value=""

Tags: html, input, colors

I have a hidden input with the value Pending. How I make the value Pending red. I've tried:

```html
<div class="email">
  <label for="cemail"></label> 
  <input type="hidden" style="font-color: red;" name="status" value="Pending" required>
</div>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: color, not font-color. You need change font-color: red to color: red

Comment: I've tried this one, didn't work. @AlexanderGorbatovsky

Comment: check it, please <div class="email">
<label for="cemail"></label> 
<input style="color: red;" name="status" value="Pending" required>
</div>

Comment: it's a hidden input, you cannot see it

Comment: @Pete It's hidden in the form but you can see it. lol

Comment: `input type="hidden"` is invisible in the front end I don't understand how you can see it

Comment: @AlexanderGorbatovsky That's weird. It works in the fiddle but it doesn't work on mine.

Comment: Maybe you have another css file try add  : !important

Comment: @LeoR. I hid the status so they cannot input it. But they can view it once they view the table. It's hidden only in the form

Comment: @JaneM perhaps you should be showing the html and css of the part that you can see

Comment: you are a bit confused.. in your example you hide INPUT and you try to color an HIDDEN INPUT, how you want we show this ?? if you want color the value in a table... color your TD value...

Comment: @LeoR. forget it adding !important worked.

Comment: CSS is proper to the div, not to the value !

Comment: Ok so you have another css anywhere

Comment: @LeoR. Guess you can post your answer, i'll accept it

Comment: @Leo R Yes, I think !important not good idea... Better find another css and add specific rule for this element

Comment: Yeah i agree with you however, here "!important" is just in one input so it can't make a lot of conflict elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use  font-color use :

```
color : red; // to color text.

background-color : red; // to color input background.
```

Comment: Yes it's works... but if your input is hidden you will not show Anythink...

Answer (score 0):

```
input[value^="Pending"] {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="email">
   <label for="cemail"></label> <input type="text" style="color: red;" name="status" value="Pending" required>
 </div>
```

Hi, Hidden fields wont be visible in browser, so i suggest first make field visible by using "text" or some other type, ref this link [HTML Input Type](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)  i have edited your code  please check.